# Visiting devise user signup page is redirecting me to my app home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.0.6.  I just installed the devise (4.3.0) gem.  I overrode the main registration controller to add some of my own params at app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :organization, :phone, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :organization, :phone, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end

end
```

but when I fire up my server and visit http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up, I'm always redirected to my home controller.  Here's my rake:routes

```
localhost:myproject davea$ rake routes
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)               registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               registrations#destroy
                         POST   /users(.:format)               registrations#create
                    root GET    /                              home#index
```

Why am I getting redirected to the home page for my sign-ups, but more importantly, how do I get the sign up page?  Am I visiting the wrong URL?

Comment: Are you using the `authenticate_user` callback in some controller? Did you try loging out and then visit `users/sign_up` again?

Comment: You are a genius -- when I cleared out the cookies on my macihne I was able to get to the sign up page.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @Dave. Try creating your own answer and accepting it.